# How to check if user already exist?

Tags: php, mysql

```
class Users {
    public $username = null;
    public $password = null;
    public $salt = "Zo4rU5Z1YyKJAASY0PT6EUg7BBYdlEhPaNLuxAwU8lqu1ElzHv0Ri7EM6irpx5w";

   public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
         if( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = stripslashes( strip_tags( >$data['username'] ) );
         if( isset( $data['password'] ) ) $this->password = stripslashes( strip_tags( >$data['password'] ) );
    }
    }

 public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
         $this->__construct( $params ); 
 }

 public function register() {
    $correct = false;
        try {
            $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)";

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();
            return "Registration Successful <br/> <a href='index.php'>Login Now</a>";
        }catch( PDOException $e ) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
 }

 }
```

I would like to check if a user already exist in my database, because it lets me create accounts with same username anytime.
Thanks.

Comment: So before you insert, select from DB where username = whatever username they entered on the reg form (security clear it first etc). if username exists (like rows >0) then tell them to pick another, else insert

Comment: Please set a unique constrain on the username column. Thus, no code checking and any race conditions wouldn't be possible.

Comment: a fixed salt is not ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a few things to help here.

1) Make your username column unique in the database.  This would prevent usernames that are not unique from being inserted.

2) Once you have a unique index on username, attempt the insert, and check for success on the insert.  Since you can get the error code from mysql, if the query was not successful and  the error code is due to a duplicate value...throw the username already exists error.

Answer (score -1):

This is the basic idea of how to return if the username exists.

```
public function username($username)
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM table WHERE username = ?");
    $sth->execute(array($username));

    $row = $sth->fetch();

    if(username == $row['username'])
    {
        do code here since username does not exist
    } else {
        echo 'username already exists';
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why it's not correct, would also be nice to understand and learn from my mistakes..

Comment: I find it to be generally unnecessary to add ANOTHER database call to see if I should make a database call for an insert.

Comment: `if($row['username'] == $row['username'])` simply worong

Comment: Works, and is a great practice are two totally different things.  Yes, your method (written properly) can do the trick.  The error in the way you wrote it is that $row['username'] == $row['username'] is always true.  I think you meant $username == $row['username']...but even  then, its still not the right solution.  If I were to do it this way, I would select the count of the rows that were returned from the query...and if count > 0...THEN insert.

Comment: You are right.. I did not notice that, that is my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sell= mysql_query("select * from `signup` where emailid='$email'");
$cntc=mysql_num_rows($sell);
if($cntc==0) {
  $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `signup`(`firstname`,`lastname`,`emailid`,`dob`,`companyname`,`phoneno`,`password`) VALUES ('$name','$lastname','$email','$dob','$comname','$phone','$pass')");
  if($sql) {
    echo'inserted successfully';
  }
} else {
  echo'Email is already exist. ';
}
```